# Finding the partial derivatives of a function in terms of the partial derivatives of another function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, solution-verification, chain-rule

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function and let $g : \mathbb R^2 →\mathbb R$ be the function defined by
$g(r, θ) := f(r \cos (θ), r \sin (θ))$. 
Answer the following questions:

1. Find the partial derivatives of $g$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$.
2. Find the partial derivatives of $f$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $g$.

My attempts:

1. $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial r} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\cosθ + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\sinθ$

And $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial θ} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial θ} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial θ} = -r\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\sin(θ) +r \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\cos(θ)$

2. We have $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial r}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial θ} = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial r}$

Are my answers correct? If not, please can you correct me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1. your notation indicated that $f$ was a function of $x$ and $y$, so in 2. your writing $\partial f/\partial r$ makes no sense.

I would suggest that in 1. you put in explicitly what $\partial x/\partial r$, etc., are in this case. Then, to do 2. correctly, solve the system of equations you have in 1. for $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$.

Comment: Can you please check my edit? If it's correct, I would solve part 2 by finding $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in terms of $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial r}$ and $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}$ right?

Comment: Yes, but you're missing an $r$ in one place.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks